# Is it possible to call class methods from the `contructor` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, es6-class

The following is an example of an ES6 Class.

```
class Car {
    constructor(brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
        // this.setBrand(brand); // how is it possible to do this?
    }
    
    setBrand(brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
    
    getBrand() {
        return this.brand;
    }
    
    getAd() {
        return `${this.brand} is the best brand out there!!`;
    }
}
```

However, since the constructor is just a repeat of the method `setBrand`, I was wondering how it would be possible to remove the redundancy and perhaps call `setBrand` from within the `constructor`.

Any pointers?

Comment: You shouldn't use **Java-style** getter/setter functions in JavaScript - is there a reason you're not using JavaScript properties (`get` and `set` keywords) instead?

Comment: Oops! I apologise. I tried this previously but somehow received an error. Oh well...

Comment: Given that JS has accessors (the `get` and `set` mentioned above) in case a need arises for properties to be computed/validated/etc., there's really no point defining `getThing` and `setThing` methods. But on *"is it possible"* did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Oh I didn't realise that `get` and `set` was the standard! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Grateful did you try out this code? You can freely call `setBrand()` in the constructor that way. The `brand` field will be created after the call. Check this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/WorldlyBetterForce)

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Yes I did try it. But I made another mistake that resulted in an error. As a result, I carelessly thought this wasn't possible! My bad!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as you suspect. In the constructor `this` is a reference to the new object so you can call class methods in it. The code below runs properly.

```js
class Car {
    constructor(brand) {
        this.setBrand(brand); // this works fine
    }
    
    setBrand(brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
    
    getBrand() {
        return this.brand;
    }
    
    getAd() {
        return `${this.brand} is the best brand out there!!`;
    }
}

let car = new Car("DeLorean")
console.log(car.getBrand())
console.log(car.getAd())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method by doing:

```
        class Car {
            constructor(brand) {
                this.setBrand(brand); <--------
            }

            setBrand(brand) {
                this.brand = brand;
            }
        }
```

in this case it's ok because you are only assigning a value to  a property, but keep in mind it's a bad practice to make the constructor do anything other than create the object.

Comment: Ooooo! I didn't realise that this was a bad practice. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts...Isn't assigning a brand, in this case, upon instantiation just considered part of creating the object?

Comment: do you mean I should only be creating an "empty" object in the constructor?

Comment: No, you can assign all the things you want in the constructor (like the brand, that's ok), but for example your car should start the motor in the constructor method, you should create a new one to do that and call it after creating a car instance not in the constructor.